# Get console job output text from dataproc using rest api

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I need to retrieve the dataproc job output text using the rest api. Only able to find logs through cloud logging.  Can someone let me know if it is possible to get the job output text retrieved through rest api or not. If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc job driver output is stored in either the staging bucket (default) or the bucket you specified when you created your cluster. You can first `get` the job resource, then get the URI through `driverOutputResourceUri`, then use GCS API to get the actual output. See this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-job-output#view_job_output) for more details.

If you use gcloud you can get `driverOutputResourceUri` with `describe`:

```
$ gcloud dataproc jobs describe spark-pi

...
driverOutputResourceUri: gs://dataproc-nnn/jobs/spark-pi/driveroutput
```

If you just want to view the output, you can use `wait`:

```
$ gcloud dataproc jobs wait 5c1754a5-34f7-4553-b667-8a1199cb9cab \
    --project my-project-id --region my-cluster-region

Waiting for job output...
INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.4.2-hadoop2 16:47:45 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at my-test-cluster-m/
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I get the output through REST API?

Comment: Yes, you can add `--log-http` in the `wait` command to see what's happening under the hood.